# parcel js and php index.php file

Tags: parcel

I need to pack and minify all and concatenate all my JS files
I am totally new to parcel and I would know if I can pack files inside a php file instead of html

ex:

```
parcel index.php
```

Any tips for people who mix php and js and that want to use parcel ?

Answer (score 1):

[Currently Parcel doesn't have any PHP support](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/262).  It's possible that support could be added via plugin, but it seems that nobody has done that yet.