# Parcel server localhost:1234 does not work

Tags: javascript, server, parcel

I have Parcel installed to compile my javascript files. According the [documentation](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html) I run parcel index.php commnad and tried to open localhost:1234 in the browser. No error in console only success message server is running on localhost:1234. But as I open the address I have 404 This localhost page can’t be found. What am I doing wrong?

Also if I try to use it like file watcher for index.js it works only for the first code update. Any other chages are not reflected in the result html..

Comment: Parcel runs a html/javascript server, not a php server.
They discussed the matter here: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/262

The php file can be added as a HtmlAsset, but will not be running/self hosting it.

Comment: What it means? And why it says server is running? Also I expect to have a modified js files but they are not. Where are the errors whatever...?

Comment: I suggest you try the basic example first, making sure everything is working as it should. https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Basic example works fine.

Comment: As I use it as watcher it does not work as expected.

Comment: From my limited experience, this just means that Parcel cannot show you the php file, as it is unable to host php in general. You can only use the Parcel built-in development hosting environment for javascript/html files.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825327/parcel-js-and-php-index-php-file

Comment: change your file index.php to index.html. it is not a PHP server